# fb:comments disappeared on all my sites

Tags: facebook, tags, comments

The Facebook comments panel suddenly disappeared from all my sites (about 4 live sites and 8 dev sites)

Obviously I did not change anything in all the sites at the same time.

Did my code suddenly become obsolete? [EDITED to show data for one of my live sites]

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
  xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"  
src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1">    </script>

<meta property="og:title" content="www.PrintMyCanvas.com Home Page" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.PrintMyCanvas.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.PrintMyCanvas.com/img/icon
  /FacebookShareIcon.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="PrintMyCanvas" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="[hidden]" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Canvas art prints made by real 
  artists with love in San Francisco! Upload your photo on our site 
  and receive your personal printing / art piece within a few days, 
  ready to hang on your wall." />
```

Could my sites have been blacklisted by Facebook?

What could have gone wrong?

Thanks,

Kyle

Answer (score 0):

We have been seeing the same problems, and https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers has been timing out on me

Answer (score 0):

Must have been a glitch at facebook, all of the comment boxes have reappeared after several days.